# Remove frozen parts from a corrupted video

Tags: ffmpeg

When dealing with corrupted videos, `ffmpeg` is a great to tool to automatically [fix errors](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/18220/fix-bad-files-and-streams-with-ffmpeg-so-vlc-and-other-players-would-not-crash/).

Is there a way, with `ffmpeg` or another similar tool, to automatically remove/drop/trim/cut away frozen parts from a file, both video and audio streams?

Using a combination of `mpdecimate` and `map` it's possible to obtain the video stream only with:

```
ffmpeg -i input.ext -vf mpdecimate -map 0:v output.mp4
```

How to do the same thing with all streams of the file, audio and video?

Given a video with two streams like:

```
     0       1         2       3         4
video|AAAAAAA|FFFFFFFFF|BBBBBBB|FFFFFFFFF|
audio|XXXXXXX|YYYYYYYYY|ZZZZZZZ|KKKKKKKKK|
```

where `A` and `B` are the good parts to mantain and `F` are the frozen parts to be trimmed away, I want obtain a "cleaned" video (with the frozen parts and its associated audio removed) which in the end would look like:

```
0       1       2
video|AAAAAAA|BBBBBBB|
audio|XXXXXXX|ZZZZZZZ|
```

Answer (score 1):

If your video has fixed frame rate, you probably mean by “frozen part” the part with the *same frame repeated many times.*

To remove duplicate frames you may apply the [mpdecimate](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#mpdecimate) filter.

Comment: Thanks to your input I have found [this question on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37088517/ffmpeg-remove-sequentially-duplicate-frames/37089629) which explains how to use it. Unfortunately using the command `ffmpeg -i in.mkv -vf mpdecimate out.mkv` reduces the file size considerably but **does not cut away** the duplicated frames: the video length remains the same.

Answer (score 0):

What you need in addition to remove the frozen parts is **setpts**. Keep in mind that **mpdecimate** works only on the video stream, so you have to remove the audio because is not going to be synced.

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -vf mpdecimate,setpts=N/FRAME_RATE/TB -an video-fixed.mp4
```